# Smart-tab in minibuffer

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, elisp

I've just found out that Hippie-expand works in the mini-buffer (via <kbd>M=/</kbd>), however I use  smart-tab (via <kbd>TAB</kbd>) for completion (and indentation) during standard editing. Hitting <kbd>TAB</kbd> in the minibuffer only inserts 4 spaces - which is something likely I'd never actually want. Is there a way to do directly Hippie-expand with smart-tab in the mini-buffer? I have completion for paths, buffers and extended commands (through ido/smex), but would like to have it for everything (e.g. for replace, search, flush/keep-line etc.) that needs input.

At the moment I use simply (Emacs 23.3):

`(setq tab-always-indent 'complete)`

although in the past I had more elaborate smart-tab settings and it also didn't work in the minibuffer...

Thank you!

Comment: In what context do you want tab completion? The minibuffer has different keymaps for isearch, file name entry, buffer switching, etc. Out of these, the latter two have tab completion out of the box.

Comment: Correct - I have autocompletion through ido for paths, buffers and I also use smex. My question concerns everything else - e.g. for search/replace and whatever else requires input through the minibuffer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need smart-tab at all to get tab minibuffer completion. You might try icomplete-mode instead:

```
(icomplete-mode +1)
```

Since smart-tab just indents or completes and in the minubuffer you never want to indent I guess it's basically the same.

Comment: I've tried it but doesn't seem to do anything... According to the emacswiki this is similar to smex which I use. I am interested here for autocompletion for all other cases (I've added clarification in the quesiton).

Answer (score 0):

[***Icicles***](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles) gives you (TAB) completion pretty much whenever the minibuffer is used, the only exceptions being when the calling code explicitly uses the minibuffer in a way that does not allow completion.

(But when constructing Lisp sexps (e.g. with <kbd>M-:</kbd>), you can use <kbd>M-TAB</kbd> to complete individual symbols.)